# Hosted Website loads with errors in <body> that are not in the code

Tags: javascript, html, c++, json, esp32

Ahoi,

I am hosting a small debug-website with my "Olimex ESP-32 POE". The goal is to send some internal data via JSON there to not have to use the Serial-Output from the Arduino IDE (The reasons behind that do not matter).

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <Update.h>
#include <string>
const char* ssid = "SSID";
const char* password = "password";
int looper = 0;
int looperSpeed = 0;
int looperMode = 0;
int looperDestination = 0;
int looperETC = 0;
WebServer webserver(80);
void initWebServer();
void getSettings() {
String response = "{";
   response+= "\"speed\": \""+(String) looperSpeed+"\"";
   response+= ",\"mode\": \""+(String) looperMode+"\"";
   response+= ",\"dest\": \""+(String) looperDestination+"\"";
   response+= ",\"etc\": \""+(String) looperETC+"\"";
   if (webserver.arg("signalStrength")== "true"){
       response+= ",\"signalStrengh\": \""+String(WiFi.RSSI())+"\"";
   }
   response+="}";
   webserver.send(200, "text/json", response);
}
void handleNotFound() {
  String message = "File Not Found\n\n";
  message += "URI: ";
  message += webserver.uri();
  message += "\nMethod: ";
  message += (webserver.method() == HTTP_GET) ? "GET" : "POST";
  message += "\nArguments: ";
  message += webserver.args();
  message += "\n";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < webserver.args(); i++) {
    message += " " + webserver.argName(i) + ": " + webserver.arg(i) + "\n";
  }
  webserver.send(404, "text/plain", message);
}
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");
  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  initWebServer();
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  // Set not found response
  webserver.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
  // Start server
  webserver.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
void loop() {
  webserver.handleClient();
  //Some test values are changed here periodically (looperXYZ)
  }
}
```

And the part which creates the website:

```
std::string online_output = "Test";
const char* serverIndex() {
  const char* o = online_output.c_str();
  const char* r = 
  (std::string("") +
  "<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js'></script>" +
  "<form method='POST' action='#' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='upload_form'>" +
     "<input type='file' name='update'>" +
          "<input type='submit' value='Update'>" +
      "</form>" +
   "<div id='prg'>Progress: 0%</div>" +
   "<div id='output' style=\"font-family: monospace; border: 1px solid black; width: 350px;min-height:398px;\">" + 
   "</div>" +
   "<script>" +
    "var id = 0;" + 
    "var removeId = 0;" + 
    "setInterval(function(){" +
    /*"var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
    "xhReq.open('GET', '/JSON', false);" +
    "xhReq.send(null);" +
    "var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhReq.responseText);" +*/
    "var data = {};" +
    "$.ajax({" +
      "type: 'GET'," +
      "url: '/JSON'," +
      "data: data," +
      "async: true," +
      "beforeSend: function (xhr) {" +
        "if (xhr && xhr.overrideMimeType) {" +
          "xhr.overrideMimeType('application/json;charset=utf-8');" +
        "}" +
      "}," +
      "dataType: 'json'," +
      "success: function (data) {" +
        "document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = \"<p id=\" + id + \" style='margin:0;padding:0px;'>\" + \"Mode: \" + fill(data.mode,2) + \" | Speed: \" + fill(data.speed,4) + \" | Dest: \" + fill(data.dest,4) + \" | ETC: \" + fill(data.etc,5) + \"</p>\" + document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;" +
       // "if (document.getElementById('output').offsetHeight > 400) document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = \"<p style='margin:0;padding:0px;'>\" + data.name + \"</p>\";" +
       "if (document.getElementById('output').offsetHeight > 400) { document.getElementById(removeId).remove(); removeId++;}" +
        "id++;" +
        "console.log(data);" +
      "}" +
    "});" +
    "}, 50);" +
    "function fill(n,m) { " + 
    "var pre=\"\";" +
    "var dec=10;" +
    "for(var i=1;i<m;i++) { if(n<dec) { pre+=\".\"; } dec*=10; }" +
    "pre = pre + n;" + 
    "return pre; }" + 
    "$('form').submit(function(e){" +
    "e.preventDefault();" +
    "var form = $('#upload_form')[0];" +
    "var data = new FormData(form);" +
    " $.ajax({" +
    "url: '/update'," +
    "type: 'POST'," +
    "data: data," +
    "contentType: false," +
    "processData:false," +
    "xhr: function() {" +
    "var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();" +
    "xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {" +
    "if (evt.lengthComputable) {" +
    "var per = evt.loaded / evt.total;" +
    "$('#prg').html('progress: ' + Math.round(per*100) + '%');" +
    "}" +
    "}, false);" +
    "return xhr;" +
    "}," +
    "success:function(d, s) {" +
    "console.log('success!')" +
   "}," +
   "error: function (a, b, c) {" +
   "}" +
   "});" +
   "});" +
   "</script>").c_str();
   return r;
}
const char* host = "esp32";
 void initWebServer() {
  if (!MDNS.begin(host)) { //http://esp32.local
    Serial.println("Error setting up MDNS responder!");
    while (1) {
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("mDNS responder started");
  /*return index page which is stored in serverIndex */
  webserver.on("/", HTTP_GET, []() {
    webserver.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
    webserver.send(200, "text/html", serverIndex());
  });
  webserver.on("/JSON", HTTP_GET, []() {
    getSettings();
  });
  /*handling uploading firmware file */
  webserver.on("/update", HTTP_POST, []() {
    webserver.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
    webserver.send(200, "text/plain", (Update.hasError()) ? "FAIL" : "OK");
    ESP.restart();
  }, []() {
    HTTPUpload& upload = webserver.upload();
    if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_START) {
      Serial.printf("Update: %s\n", upload.filename.c_str());
      if (!Update.begin(UPDATE_SIZE_UNKNOWN)) { //start with max available size
        Update.printError(Serial);
      }
    } else if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_WRITE) {
      /* flashing firmware to ESP*/
      if (Update.write(upload.buf, upload.currentSize) != upload.currentSize) {
        Update.printError(Serial);
      }
    } else if (upload.status == UPLOAD_FILE_END) {
      if (Update.end(true)) { //true to set the size to the current progress
        Serial.printf("Update Success: %u\nRebooting...\n", upload.totalSize);
      } else {
        Update.printError(Serial);
      }
    }
  });
  webserver.begin();
}
```

This is testing code, so there might be left-overs from previous tests - FYI.

When loading the website (currently I am using Chrome) it sometimes works, sometimes nothing is loaded (THIS SITE IS NOT WORKING, and then an empty page) and sometimes I get a result like: `xV­ºùÿý?øÿý?;">` which is the only output on the screen.

In detail it shows the following:

```
<html><head></head><body>xV&shy;ºùÿý?øÿý?;"&gt;<script>var id = 0; [...the rest of the <script> part is loaded properly...]
```

I just noticed that in front of these strange characters are 364 centered points (·) but I cannot actually copy them, no editor is displaying them besides the Chrome->Inspect->"Sources"-Tab.

So basically the body is broken and these characters appear, they also do not change currently.

Can someone point me into a direction to solve this on my own, so that the website is always correctly loaded or knows what the error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be on the following line:

```
const char* r = (std::string("") + “...”).c_str();
```

You are creating and `std::string` which allocates the raw c string on the heap. You then get the c representation of the string with `.c_str()`. The issue is that the string is freed since you have not assigned the string to a variable of type `std::string`. As a result, you were accessing memory that was not yours. When its memory wasn’t yet reused, it worked, but want is was reused by another program, it failed since you got basically random bytes from memory.

You can solve the issue by adding the following:

```
auto my_str = std::string("") + “...”;
```

Because you don’t need the raw pointer.

For the server index function, it should look like:
`std::string serverIndex() {`

For your init web server function:

```
webserver.on("/", HTTP_GET, []() {
    webserver.sendHeader("Connection", "close");
    auto r = serverIndex();
    webserver.send(200, "text/html", r.c_str());
});
```

Disclaimer: this code wasn’t tested as it was only written in the app.

Comment: That seems to make sense to me, yet the problem remains after changing those lines. (Thank you for the quick reply.)

Comment: I’ll look into it!

Comment: I deleted the function serverIndex() and made it the const char* it actually is with your two lines included and it works now. So maybe there has been some additional error with this function. Now I always get an "This website is not working" but after half a second it loads. That might because of the server.clienthandle().

Comment: Ok great! Can you mark the question as answered than?